# Show a warning when there are duplicate headings in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, warning

Sometimes I have quite long org-mode documents. I tend to insert new headings and sub-headings throughout the whole document. However sometimes I think that I already used this text and begin searching in the document. The easier way would be to just insert the heading and have org-mode show some warning when this exact text exists somewhere in the document as heading. Currently I think best would be if the color of the heading changes.
Is this possible and if yes, how can this be done?

Comment: Hm, this should be specified in greater detail. For an example, each section of a book might have a subsection named _Motivation_ or _Introduction_. Does your proposal only concern the headings at the same level in the same branch of the document?

Comment: Well, tough question. ;) I'd say that for my usecase every level in the same branch of the document is of concern.

Comment: your options include using a function in org-mode-hook to tell you if there are duplicates when you open the file, or in before-save-hook to tell you if there are duplicates before you save, or a function that uses something like helm/ivy to insert a new headline that is unique.